# Подстановка HTML атрибутов в заданную строку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно записать регулярное выражение для следующей строки:`<a href="/images/gallery/1.JPG"><img alt=" " src="/images/gallery/1.JPG" style="width: 700px; height: 394px; border-width: 5px; border-style: solid; margin: 5px;" /></a>`
Т.е. мне нужно будет через `preg_replace` заменить во всех таких строках alt. 
Заранее благодарю.

Пытался проверить примерно так: ';

```
if(preg_match_all('/(((\<a href="((.*)"\>)+)(\<img ((.*)) src="(.*)"/\>+(<\/a\>))+$/', $string))
echo "YES";
```

А на месте alt="" мне нужно задать , вытащив из базы alt и title.

Comment: а сами что-то пытались? что? и еще: заменить `alt` на что?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fS8gE2/1 или даже https://regex101.com/r/fS8gE2/2

Comment: Visman, благодарю, очень полезный ответ и ресурс. Продублируйте, пожалуйста, свой комментарий в ответ, чтобы я мог его отметить как верный.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

В строке `$string` находит все `$search`  и заменяет их на `$replace`.

Пример:

```
$result = str_replace('alt=""', 'alt="privet"', 'img src="" alt=""');
```

Из строки `img src="" alt=""` получаем строку `img src="" alt="privet"`